# In search of a word

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for a person who is always concerned with how people look,  describing outer appearances as a reference to who they are?

Answer (score -1):

superficial. From Dictionary.com:

"concerned with or comprehending only what is on the surface or obvious:
a superficial observer."